# Is it possible to prevent .NET runtime from unloading DLLs on exit?

Tags: python, .net, qt, pyqt

We're writing a mixed mode application in Python, Qt4 (4.6.1 at the moment) and .NET (for integration reasons).

Now, when the app exists normally, the .NET runtime is unloaded, which sens PROCESS_DETACH to all DLLs. This seem to cause a crash when QHostInfoLookupManager' destriuctor estrys the threadpool.

Is there some way to prevent this, besides:

- TerminateProcess?
- Move .NET code to separate process to avoid Qt issues.

The call stack is as follows, when I get a crash:

```
python26.dll!1e02edbf()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for python26.dll]  
python26.dll!1e078aba()     
QtCore.pyd!01971058()   
QtCore4.dll!qt_message_output(QtMsgType msgType=QtWarningMsg, const char * buf=0x077526a8)  Line 2223 + 0x1c bytes  C++
QtCore4.dll!qt_message(QtMsgType msgType=QtWarningMsg, const char * msg=0x671b8464, char * ap=0x0012f1d4)  Line 2297    C++
QtCore4.dll!qWarning(const char * msg=0x671b8464, ...)  Line 2378 + 0x11 bytes  C++
QtCore4.dll!QWaitCondition::~QWaitCondition()  Line 156 C++
QtCore4.dll!QThreadPoolPrivate::~QThreadPoolPrivate()  + 0xa2 bytes C++
QtCore4.dll!QThreadPoolPrivate::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x8 bytes C++
QtCore4.dll!QObject::~QObject()  Line 992 + 0x16 bytes  C++
QtCore4.dll!QThreadPool::~QThreadPool()  Line 430 + 0xf bytes   C++
QtNetwork4.dll!QHostInfoLookupManager::~QHostInfoLookupManager()  Line 454 + 0x23 bytes C++
QtNetwork4.dll!QHostInfoLookupManager::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x8 bytes  C++
QtNetwork4.dll!`theHostInfoLookupManager'::`8'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'cleanup''()  + 0x14 bytes   C++
QtNetwork4.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle=0x00385f30, unsigned long dwReason=3694344, void * lpreserved=0x00385f08)  Line 449  C
QtNetwork4.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x64000000, unsigned long dwReason=0, void * lpreserved=0x00000000)  Line 560 + 0x8 bytes  C
QtNetwork4.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle=0x64000000, unsigned long dwReason=0, void * lpreserved=0x00000001)  Line 510 + 0xe bytes   C
ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_LdrShutdownProcess@0()  - 0xfe bytes 
kernel32.dll!__ExitProcess@4()  + 0x42 bytes    
kernel32.dll!7c81cb26()     
mscorwks.dll!SafeExitProcess()  + 0xb7 bytes    
mscorwks.dll!DisableRuntime()  - 0x199708 bytes 
mscoreei.dll!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes()  + 0x873e bytes   
mscoreei.dll!_CorExitProcess@4()  + 0x26 bytes  
mscoree.dll!_ShellShim_CorExitProcess@4()  + 0x94 bytes 
msvcr90.dll!__crtCorExitProcess(int status=0)  Line 716 C
msvcr90.dll!__crtExitProcess(int status=0)  Line 722 + 0x8 bytes    C
msvcr90.dll!doexit(int code=0, int quick=0, int retcaller=0)  Line 632  C
msvcr90.dll!exit(int code=0)  Line 412 + 0xc bytes  C
python26.dll!1e030405()     
python26.dll!1e02cd93()     
python26.dll!1e02e887()     
python26.dll!1e02ccba()     
MyApp.exe!orz::runPythonFile(const char * file=0x00a203f0, QDir pydir={...}, QString pypath={...})  Line 66 + 0x3e bytes    C++
MyApp.exe!orz::the_main(int argc=2, char * * argv=0x003860e0)  Line 132 + 0x50 bytes    C++
MyApp.exe!main(int argc=2, char * * argv=0x003860e0)  Line 152 + 0xd bytes  C++
MyApp.exe!_WinMain@16()  + 0xb8 bytes   
kernel32.dll!_BaseProcessStart@4()  + 0x23 bytes
```

Maybe there's something my message handling, but I don't want the dll unload from .net anyway. I tried altering the my logging a bit to avoid the python call, but then I  get stuck "no usermode threads running, app is deadlocked",  seems related to http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20462.

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()  
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0xc bytes  
kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectEx@12()  + 0x8b bytes  
kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObject@8()  + 0x12 bytes 
QtCore4.dll!QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex * mutex=0x07ccf200, unsigned long time=4294967295)  Line 175 + 0x15 bytes   C++
QtCore4.dll!QThreadPoolPrivate::waitForDone()  Line 295 + 0x10 bytes    C++
QtCore4.dll!QThreadPool::~QThreadPool()  Line 429   C++
```

Qt does not support dll unloading, as quoted from the above post

> “To be perfectly honest, I don’t know what to do with this task. I
>   seem to recall seeing cases where Windows threads would disappear at
>   application exit, yet the HANDLE to those threads would not be
>   signaled (meaning your app would deadlock if waiting on the handle).
>
> I am tempted to simply mark this as “Out of Scope”, since, as Thiago
>   says, we do not test nor really support unloading the Qt libraries
>   from the application once they have been loaded.”

Comment: It sounds like the Qt DLL is misbehaving - DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is sent as part of *any* application shutdown. See [old new thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx) post related to this.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I guess that's just C++ running all the destructors, which does  happen. I suppose it QHostInfoLookupManager simply should not close the QThreadPool at all in it's dtor.

Comment: @Macke, have you found solution for this problem? I got stuck with something similar.

Comment: @black_wizard: Not really. We just run TerminateProcess() instead of the regular exit. I suppose separating it into two processes would be the only "proper" workaround, or just changing some code in Qt to avoid the problem (i.e. leaking the QThreadPool object to the OS on shutdown, which is what is done when quitting normally anyway...)